# How does Facebook represent bold word

Tags: python, string, facebook

The bold letter of Facebook does not match with normal word

For example:-

Thailand smart city expo 2022 is different from      how can I match them.

This is what I try

```
str = '    '

x = str.find("Thailand Smart City")
```

it returns -1

Comment: Are you talking about the HTML file you're viewing in your browser?  If so, then just look at it.  See what HTML they're using.  They're probably using either a font tag or a class.